# How to Rotate camera only in X-axis with mouse click and drag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I rotate camera around the X-axis only?

The below code does not function only in X-axis but in all axes.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
                float XaxisRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*rotationSpeed;
               transform.RotateAround (Vector3.right, XaxisRotation);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using `RotateAround()` function before so the camera was rotating in all 3 Axes. Using only `Rotate()` with Vector3.right makes the camera rotate in the X axis only.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
               float XaxisRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*10f;
               transform.Rotate (Vector3.right, XaxisRotation);

        }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: Ah sorry for that. I was using RotateAround() function before which is why the camera was rotating in all 3 Axes whereas using only Rotate with Vector3.right helps to rotate in the X axis only.